# AngularJS Rebind Directive '='

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a series of reusable controls. I need an elegant solution to rebind the directive to a new reference.

```
scope: {
    model:'='
}
```

```html
<my-directive data-model="vm.models.invoice"></my-directive>
```

Now how can I update invoice here to a new object and have the directive update to the new reference?

Parent controller sets the invoice it's passing in to the child directive:

```
vm.models.invoice = { id: 1};
```

Edit: I'm trying to avoid doing a hacky ng-if / $timeout combo.

Comment: Is binding with `'='` absolutely necessary? If switching to `'<'` is viable then you could use `$onChanges` inside a controller for your directive to detect any model rebinding attempts.

Comment: I was reading about '<'. I'll need to check it out. The control does need to set some data. I use 1.2 at work but for this project I'm using 1.7  so some of the newer things I'm not used to using.

Comment: I'd thoroughly recommend one-way data binding (i.e. `'<'`) over the two-way version, unless you really need the latter for some reason. Even if your directive needs to potentially update the input model (i.e. `vm.models.invoice` in your example), you can solve this by introducing a callback binding that effectively informs parents (i.e. controller) to update their bindings and then to have that eventually flow back down. This is the whole premise of unidirectional data flow and is more sane to reason about.